# How to switch between automatic GUI login to CLI login in RHEL8.1

Tags: rhel

What is the command allowing to switch between automatic GUI login to CLI login in RHEL8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To always boot with CLI, run:

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

To always boot in with GUI, run:

```
systemctl set-default graphical.target
```